# How to build hierarchical ACL/ACE with Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, acl, database-performance, hierarchical

Is there any way to build hierarchical ACL with Symfony2?
I need to build an admin area with a simple Category/Article one-to-many relation. Is there any way to build ACLs so that every ACE on the category propagates on the related articles if not further ACE is specified on the Article?

Let's say I build some categories and articles and I build the following ACL for the User1

```
Example:
Category1 (Read Write)
    Article1
    Article2 (Read)
...
CategoryN
    Article1
    ...
    ArticleN
```

You end up with:

```
Category1 -> Can be read or modified
Article1 -> Can be read or modified
Article2 -> Can only be read
```